# Swift convert cURL -user key to json for AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, curl, afnetworking

I have a cURL request structured as so:

```
curl -X POST http://host.com \
    --data token=myToken \
    --data foo=myFoo \
    --user myUsername:myPassword
```

I structure the data parameters:

```
let params = ["token" : myToken, "foo" : myFoo]
```

Then POST using AFNetworking.

```
manager.POST("http://host.com", parameters: params, progress: nil, success: { task, responseObject in
        //stuff
        }, failure: { operation, error in
        //error stuff    
    })
```

But how do I add the necessary parameters from the cURL `--user` key to this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learned something, `-u` or `--user` is the same as Basic auth.  And you can pass the username and password through an authorization header like so, where `base64Encode()` is my own string extension to convert to base64.

The full conversion for:

```
curl -X POST http://host.com \
--data token=myToken \
--data foo=myFoo \
--user myUsername:myPassword
```

Would be like so:

```
let params = ["token" : myToken, "foo" : myFoo]

if let base64 = "myUsername:myPassword".base64Encode() {

    manager.requestSerializer.setValue("Basic " + base64, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    manager.POST("http://host.com", parameters: params, progress: nil, success: { task, responseObject in
        //stuff
        }, failure: { operation, error in
            //error stuff
    })
}
```